# Possible to make editor.getData() returns content with inline styles in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Here is my question:
When inserting tables, we get content by editor.getData() like:

```
<figure class="table"><table><tbody><tr><td>....... <table></figure>
```

In my case, what I actually want is:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid #00THJ...">....</table>
```

The reason is that the content will be used in my outlook and then sent as email.

we are trying to resolve using many ways but it's not working we don't have idea what user can make